# Aurelia removeEventListener from dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I added eventlistener to dynamically added element in aurelia template.
I now need to remove the listener from the element when detaching the page.
I need a way to reference that element in order to remove the listener from it.

I'm aware of the `ref` keyword in the HTML, to reference an element to the VM - so maybe this is the way to solve it. I tried to add it dynamically to the element, but couldn't see it in the source view.

See below:

```
// this is the dynamically created element:
var cancelDiv = createDiv("cancel");
cancelDiv.addEventListener('click', this.DoSomething.bind(this));

// Trying to add attribute:
<element>.attributes["ref"] = <refValue>;
//or
<element>['ref'] = <refValue>;
```

> **Reaching the element by querying the DOM is not an option because the element is part of template and may appear several times in the page

Comment: I'd like to know why you are trying to do that instead of using Aurelia bindings to begin with.

Comment: @Balázs - Sorry - I'm quite newbie to aurelia - I didn't quite understand what you mean- how can I get **cancelDiv** which was created dynamically and remove the event listener which was attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong approach. Don't attach events to individual elements, use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) instead. The premise is simple, instead of many events you attach one event listener to a parent element and capture all events of the children.

**Say your markup is this and each of those DIV's with class of `item` are added/removed dynamically.**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Your approach is putting events on each of those child DIV's which is going to cause you a lot of pain.

**The approach you should be doing is the following using Aurelia's delegate binding:**

```
<template>
    <div click.delegate="itemClicked($event)">
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Then inside of your accompying view-model, you create the above method and get the passed event:**

```
export class MyClass {
    itemClicked(e) {
        console.log(e.target); // e.target is the target element, so any of the clicked children
    }
}
```

The upside of `delegate` is that it will clean up after itself, detaching event listeners without needing to a single thing.